# Type Mismatch: Range Formula

Tags: excel, vba, formula, mismatch

I am completely at a loss as to why I am getting the "type mismatch" error.

The error appears on the Range(RelAddy).Formula line.

```
Sub CallingUserformAssignJC()

BeforeLastRow = Sheets("Information").Cells(Rows.Count, 19).End(xlUp).Row
Sheets("Information").Range("U2:U" & BeforeLastRow).ClearContents

LastRowAC = Sheets("Information").Cells(Rows.Count, 19).End(xlUp).Row
LastCol = Sheets("Today").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

For j = 1 To LastCol
    CurrLastRow = Sheets("Today").Cells(Rows.Count, j).End(xlUp).Row
    startAddy = Sheets("Today").Cells(2, j + 1).Address
    endAddy = Sheets("Today").Cells(CurrLastRow, j + 1).Address
    RelAddy = Sheets("Today").Cells(CurrLastRow + 1, j + 1).Address
    Range(RelAddy).Formula = "=COUNTA(" & Sheets("Today").Range(startAddy, endAddy) & ")"
    unassignedMilestone = Sheets("Today").Cells(CurrLastRow + 1, j + 1).Value
    Do While unassignedMilestone <> 0
        frmAssignJC.Show
        frmAssignJC.Hide
    Loop
    j = j + 3
Next j

End Sub
```

I have looked at the locals window, and startAddy, endAddy, and RelAddy are all type Variant/String. Any help would be appreciated thank you.

Comment: what does `debug.print` say the value of `Sheets("Today").Range(startAddy, endAddy)` is?

Comment: @braX it says it is an empty variant. But startAddy and endAddy both have values assigned to them in the locals window

Comment: And what values would those be?

Comment: @braX startAddy = "$B$2" endAddy = "$B$3"

Comment: @abbsichel are you declaring your variables anywhere? (I don't see that here)

Comment: @GlennG no, I am not. I understand it's a bad habit not to declare my variables but I don't like to for some reason.

Comment: If you want to insert a formula via VBA you have to build a string as if you were entering it in the sheet. Think about what you would type and then compare to what you trying to use - how does it differ?

Comment: @abbsichel ok, was just checking in case it was a case of misspell and accidentally created new variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in `Range("B2").Formula = "=COUNTA(" & Sheets("Today").Range(startAddy, endAddy) & ")"`

Try `Range("B2").Formula = "=COUNTA(" & Sheets("Today").Range(startAddy, endAddy).Address & ")"`

In order to use a formula you need to get the Address of the range instead of just the range

Comment: So simple, how did I not see that?? Thank you so much!!

Comment: another way to write that (maybe not the most correct way) is `Range(RelAddy).Formula = "=COUNTA('Today'!" & StartAddy & ":" & EndAddy & ")"`